# List of allowable tags on PHP's strip_tags()

Tags: php, function, strip-tags

This is a typical example of how someone whould use the [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

```
<h1><?php echo htmlentities($post->title); ?></h1>

// post content here
<?php echo strip_tags($post->content); ?>
```

So, I've created an alias function for stripping tags, like this:

```
function strip($var) {
        $allowed = '<div><span><pre><p><br><hr><hgroup><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6>
            <ul><ol><li><dl><dt><dd><strong><em><b><i><u>
            <img><a><abbr><address><blockquote><area><audio><video>
            <form><fieldset><label><input><textarea>
            <caption><table><tbody><td><tfoot><th><thead><tr>
            <iframe>';

        return strip_tags($var, $allowed);
    }
```

and use this instead:

```
<h1><?php echo htmlentities($post->title); ?></h1>

// post content here
<?php echo strip($post->content); ?>
```

My question is do I need to add more tags in the $allowed array, or remove some?
Which other tags are considered 'not-evil' to add on the array?

Comment: <sup> and <sub> are quite gentle, you could add them.

Comment: even `<img>` can be used as `EVIL`

Comment: @dwhite.me 'Evil' mean tags like <script>, that's why I strip them out.

Comment: @TechnoKnol You may be right, what I'm trying to do is to come up with a list of tags that could do less or no harm in cases like posts.

Comment: I'd think you'll have more luck targeting the evil ones rather than nice ones, there should presumably be less of them if it's only really script, img, iframe and so on

Comment: <iframe> & <img> are first tags to exclude If security are your concern.

Comment: @dwhite.me I think targeting the evil ones would be more easy, but php strip_tags takes the 'allowable_tags' as second parameter.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj The reason why I have <iframe> & <img> is because in a post there could also be images, that are inserted/uploaded via a filemanager, or the <iframe> is used to display for example a youtube video.

Comment: if we look deeper in the direction of security issues, then the best advise is to use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: why is your `$allowed` an array with one (string) element? shouldn't it be just a string?

Comment: You 're wright. My mistake. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are worried about <kbd>[XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)</kbd> attacks than [this is the best cheat sheet I ever use.](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)

*updated the link*